# What is in BLE Advertising data?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to implement Bluetooth low energy in one of my projects, using an iPhone and a HM-0 BLE module.

My question: is it possible to read service UUIDs (or even their characteristics) after scanning, without having to actually connect to the peripheral?

The point is whether or not it is possible to put the list of Service UUIDs and the value of their characteristics on the advertising data.

Comment: Let's edit this to be either about what is possible with BLE or how to code your scanning app. If you want to take this in the code direction, please read [ask] and show us what you've gotten so far for a library / code example and explain where you are having a problem. If it's not about code, let's get that out of the question and focus on what part of BLE specifications you are struggling with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to achieve what you want is to add the available services to the advert report. This functionality is module-dependent and there are many modules that do not allow you to do that. I had a quick look at the AT commands of the HM-10 and it seems that this module is one of them.

Please note that with BLE you can add whatever you want to the advert report, and program your iPhone to read the data accordingly. However, If you want full-fledged BLE communication (i.e. reading characteristic values, etc) then your best option is to connect to the device.

For more information, take a look at these useful links:

- http://letsmakerobots.com/node/38009
- http://letsmakerobots.com/node/39795
- http://www.jnhuamao.cn/download_rom_en.asp?id=66

I hope that this helps.

Comment: And to clarify, "connect" in BLE is a little different than in Bluetooth 2.1 - In 2.1 you had to pair, potentially involving an exchange of keys and a passcode.  In BLE you only need to pair if an attribute is flagged as requiring encryption, so it is possible to connect to a device without needing user intervention to enter the pairing key - so it is less of an issue that with BT 2.1